# Negative Charge Pump- How to analyze this?

Tags: inverter, cmos

[image]

I am using CMOS 4069 inverter and wired up this circuit. I want to generate a \$-V_{dd}\$ negative pulse and \$2V_{dd}\$ positive pulse. The circuit above is for the negative voltage. However, I get really low negative voltage. In the analysis of the circuit, I couldn't get about the on-off regions of the mosfet when the square wave is sent. Could anyone help me with the analysis?
Another small question - shouldn't \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$ be negative for the MOSFETs to be in ON-region? Thank you.

Comment: Such charge pumps are always going to have a volt drop on each conversion stage.  That circuit looks like a pump and active rectifier in one.  What voltage are you running the 4069 at, what current are you drawing from the -ve rail?

Comment: @KalleMP I am giving an input voltage of Vdd=5V and getting a negative voltage output of -0.5V approximately. Current... I didn't measure, I will measure and tell you.

Comment: If you have no load you should get 'close' to your specified voltage.  The type of charge pump I have dealt with is similar to the one at the link http://www.eeweb.com/blog/extreme_circuits/circuit-project-5v-powered-charge-pump-battery-charger  You rearrange the diodes to select negative voltage. Your circuit might even be 'isolated' and could have a different ground reference because the power is fed through two capacitors, kind of neat but needs caps twice as large.

Comment: The Wikipedia article may have some ideas, they show how to chain these isolated circuits to increase the pumped voltage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier#Cross-coupled_switched_capacitor